# Facebook like button on my site and Facebook page of my company

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

On my site, some people like me, I have 100 likes let's say.
On the facebook page of my site, I have only 1 person liking me, because they are all liking me through the "like" button on my site.
I want to merge those 2 counts. Whenever somebody press "like" on my site, he is automatically liking my site's facebook page too.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible, what IS possible is to get people to like the site rather than the pages URL,

Just hardcode the url in like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2example.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Where "http://example.com" is your URL